# anaconda - downgrade the cudnn to be compatable with tensorflow 1.15

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda

I have tensorflow 1.15 installed on my anaconda environment, and keras 2.3.1. also, windows 10 and python 3.6.  based on [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#tested_build_configurations), it seems like I need cudnn 5. but the one that conda installed for me is 7.6.5.

when I try to run `conda install cudnn==5`, or `cudnn==5.1`, I get:

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
```

any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: Conda has *never* distributed cudnn version 5. The oldest version is 7.0.5, built for CUDA 8. You can use conda itself to see what is available

Answer (score -1):

you must have the miniconda2 == 4.5.4 version